# Find intersection of two sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

{m ∈ Z, ∃ j ∈ Z ∋ m = 3j } ∩ {n ∈ Z, ∃ k ∈ Z ∋ n = 7k}

Here is my attemp: {∅, 21, 63, 189,....}
Not sure if this right but can someone please help me out on this ? Thank You

Comment: Can you describe the sets (in the first line) in words?

Comment: the fist set: m is all integer, there is integer j such that m=3j

Comment: the second set: n is all integer, there is integer k such that n=3k. Thank You for reply

Comment: And I need to find the intersection between these two sets

Comment: Can you list [some of] the elements of the sets?

Comment: The first set:{∅,3,6,9,...21,...,63...} The second set:{∅,7,14,21,...63...}. The second set should be n=7k. I typed it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for fixing the typo.

In plain English, we want to find "the integers that are both multiples of 3 and multiples of 7." This is precisely the same as "the integers that are multiples of 21."

Your answer is almost correct. First, the empty set $\varnothing$ is not an integer, so it should not be in any of the sets. Second, you have forgotten $0$ and negative numbers. You have also forgotten a few other integers, like 42.

Comment: so do you have any better way to express this ? can I just write like {...,-21,0,21,63,189,...} I think there should be a better way to write this.

Comment: What you have written is fine (although you have forgotten $42$, as I mentioned above). You can also use the notation used in the question.

Comment: that help very much ... thank you a lot.